# How to push a new value into a JSON object

Tags: perl

I have an empty JSON object

```
{}
```

I would like to know how, in Perl, I could push values into the object so it'd end up looking like this

```
{"Test": 1}
```

Comment: Quite confusing. Where do you have that "empty JSON object"? In a string in the perl program? Elsewhere?

Comment: What exactly do you have? If your code looks like `my $obj = {}` then you have a reference to a *Perl hash*, which you may convert to JSON if you wish. If it looks like `my $obj = "{}"` then you have a Perl string, which is valid JSON notation

Comment: @Borodin Yeah string, it looks like: my $json = "{}" and I want to push Test with the value 1 so when it's printed it looks like {"Test": 1}

Comment: Although a bit useless if the string is actually "{}" you could decode_json it, stuff whatever you want to stuff in it and then encode_json it, just like @AntonPetrusevich suggests.

Answer (score 5):

You should build your data as a Perl data structure, and convert it to JSON when it is complete

If you were starting with some significant JSON data then you would decode it first and then add to the resultant Perl data structure, but it is trivial to create an empty Perl hash to start with

Your code would look like this

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use JSON;

my %data;

$data{Test} = 1;

my $convert = JSON->new->pretty;
print $convert->encode(\%data);
```

#### output

```
{
   "Test" : 1
}
```

Comment: Now how can I check whether a key exists in an object?

Comment: @user3394199: There is no "object": you are dealing with a simple Perl data structure. Perhaps you should take a look at [perlintro](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlintro.html)? You need the `exists` operator to determine whether an element with the given key exists in a hash

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use JSON;
my $obj = {};
$obj->{'Test'} = 1;
print encode_json ($obj) . "\n";
```

A little bit of google-fu returns tutorial sites like [JSON in Perl](http://perlmaven.com/json)

Comment: Now how can I check whether a key exists in an object?

Comment: if(exists $obj->{'Test'}) { ... }